# Disable CKEditor annoying tooltip?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

on ckeditor, when using div content-editable=true (ckeditor inline editing), there are tooltip "Rich Text Editor, the_id_of_that_div" that shown when mouse is hovered to that div, anyone know how to disable that?

i have google for it but, havent found anything about that..

ckeditor version 4.0

why i consider that tooltip annoying? because it covers another input box and the ckeditor toolbar..

Comment: ah yeah, sorry.. i will close this question..

Comment: the other question didn't have an answer

Comment: Sorry, but I see there an answer. It mentions that this is known issue and is already reported.

Comment: See http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-title