# How to disable tooltips in Yii2 2amigos CKEditor

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, ckeditor

I have these annoying tooltips in 2amigos CKEditor that obstruct and hide the content of a text area. How can I disable them?
I have tried to use

```
     config.language="en-gb";
      config.title="Put your title here";
```

and

```
    CKEDITOR.config.title = false;
```

as shown in the links below but it seems that was a long time ago and those options no longer exist
[Disable CKEditor annoying tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935458/disable-ckeditor-annoying-tooltip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/issues/387#issuecomment-382663741) you can easily remove the tooltips via CSS:

```
.ck.ck-button .ck.ck-tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

I've just tried it on https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/ and it seems to work.